# Meteor finding an object with id

Tags: meteor

Assume I have an id string that looks like `557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1` which is stored in session. I try to retrieve a document whose `_id` is same as above, but I fail to find it even though it exists.

```
Posts.findOne({_id: "557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1"});
```

returns undefined. The existing object looks like following:

[image]

I can make it work by doing

```
var id = "557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1";
var posts = Posts.find().fetch();
var post = _.filter(posts, function (post) { return post._id._str === id });
return post
```

but it seems dirty. Here's my console inputs and outputs to further investigate this behavior (`Posts == Applicants`). You will notice that even though the document that we are looking for definitely exists, I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand why your `_id` is wrapped into `_str`. Did you try with `Posts.findOne({_id._str: "557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1"});`?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Thank you, but that's not syntactically correct. Meteor wraps `_id` for a document from MongoDB I think.

Answer (score 11):

You have to define _id as a `Mongo.ObjectID` to represent the [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) type correctly.

```
Posts.findOne({_id: new Mongo.ObjectID("557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1") });
```

One caveat of ObjectIDs with Meteor is their timestamps aren't correct. Particularly if they're inserted on the client.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect, as Meter doesn't use normal Mongo IDs and you will get an error. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222799/meteor-returns-invalid-hexadecimal-string-error-trying-to-create-objectid for more details

Answer (score 1):

Akshat's answer will probably work, but `new Mongo.ObjectID("557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1")` will generate a new ID and if you are trying to update a record or find a record it won't find any.

I would do something like this:

```
function findPostById(id) {
  let newMongoObjectId = new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID();
  newMongoObjectId._str = id;
  Posts.findOne({_id: newMongoObjectId._str});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
var id = "557fba5a8032a674d929e6a1";
Posts.findOne({'_id.str': id});
```

Hope it helps