# Meteor returns invalid hexadecimal string error trying to create ObjectID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I'm inserting some stuff into the database and updating it elsewhere using jQuery (give me a break, I'm new), after which I need to be able to click it and display some UI stuff, which means getting the ID. So I set the ID variable and then try and and then try and use it in the click event:

```
...

"click .message-entry" : function (e) {
    var id = this._id || new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(newMessageId);
    Session.set('singleMessageId', id);
},

...
```

Should work in principle, however I get the following error returned:

`Uncaught Error: Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID`

A breakpoint reveals that the ID is both a string and the ID of the newly inserted document. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: (give me a break, I'm new) ?? So you are aware this may be the wrong approach, but feel it's more important to hack this together than possibly be shown a better approach? Inserting/updating items in the db and displaying them is a trivial task when you follow the established patterns.

Comment: Anyway, what is the `newMessageId` variable you are passing to Meteor.Collection.ObjectID?

Comment: Also the api is now [`new Mongo.ObjectID([hexString])`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id)

Comment: @JeremyK it's for a personal project that I need to finish asap. The variable is the ID string of the inserted document as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 7):

By default, Meteor doesn't use Mongo's hexadecimal object IDs. You could either tell Meteor to use Mongo style IDs by passing `{idGeneration: 'MONGO'}` into [`new MongoCollection()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection), or (probably more easily) just use `newMessageID` instead of `new Mongo.ObjectID(newMessageID)`, if the value of `newMessageID` is the `_id` returned by `insert()`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.