# Meteor insert creating a weird _id value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So, I created some simple app to play with Meteor in order to learn it, and everything worked just fine a few weeks ago. But, after coming back from my vacation I updated meteor to the latest version and now all of a sudden, the insert method creates some weird _id values.

Namely, I populate my database with random values and the _id values are all proper 24 character hexadecimal strings like 562a3d8de2547280a275088a and so on. For that I use mongo insert like this:

```
db.simpletable.insert({ name: 'LbDM7kbZf', email: 'E7vfcDZi@yahoo.com', age: 32 });
db.simpletable.insert({ name: 'I6UClhz', email: 'DIZ15@yahoo.com', age: 44 });
db.simpletable.insert({ name: 'XeE3vNz', email: 'X0nUFJUshm@yahoo.com', age: 33 });
...
```

However, when I call the .insert from Meteor, the _id value is a 17 character string like this `tJ3PXRmjderbu9oKF` and on the client I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID
```

I have no idea how to fix this or even where to look since the insert is painfully simple:

```
SimpleTable = new Mongo.Collection("simpletable");

SimpleTable.insert({
    name: aObj.name,
    email: aObj.email,
    age: aObj.age
});
```

[image]

Comment: The "_id" is not weird (it's not a bug, it's a feature, as Ryan Wu points out. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222799/meteor-returns-invalid-hexadecimal-string-error-trying-to-create-objectid

Comment: Ryans comment was not clear to me. I figured it out from your link. I changed the Mongo.Collection call to SimpleTable = new Mongo.Collection("simpletable", { idGeneration: 'MONGO' }); and that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `, { idGeneration: 'MONGO' }` fixed the problem:

```
SimpleTable = new Mongo.Collection("simpletable", { idGeneration: 'MONGO' });
```

Thanks **B. Clay Shannon** for the link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228422

Answer (score 1):

That is the `ObjectId` auto generated from [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), you can use it as the identifier or primary key of your data

Comment: I dont get it :( Whats the difference between the 562a3d8de2547280a275088a and the tJ3PXRmjderbu9oKF, why is it different when they are both autocreated when I call the insert method and most importantly, how can I make sure that always the longer one is being created? :(